# Where are SSH init scripts located?

Tags: ssh, openbsd, init-script

I'm following the best security practices of SSH, via this [link](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html) and the link states:

> We should remove the unused keys and only generate a large RSA key and an Ed25519 key. Your init scripts may recreate the unused keys. If you don’t want that, remove any ssh-keygen commands from the init script.

However I can't find where this init script is located to remove the `ssh-keygen` command. I don't want my OS to recreate DSA and EDCSA keys at boot. I tried many places I thought it might be located, like `/etc/rc.d` and similar. My OS is OpenBSD 5.7

Comment: +1 for a good guide on SSH security practices. Want to know that too!

Comment: Don't remove the keys or modify the init scripts. Instead disable the keys in `sshd_config`.

Comment: In a very secure server nobody would use this keys anyway...there's no reason to even let them exist

Comment: Yes, but if you modify any init script you're going to mess up the updates. The sshd_config method is the cleaner one to disable obsolete algorithms. The output of `sysmerge` during the updates will be more simple.

Comment: By updates you mean like upgrading to 5.8 ? I would just download 5.8 iso and format it anyway. But if i knew that before i would just create a copy .backup but now is too late lol

Comment: You don't need to backup the scripts. These are available within the tarball `etc57.tgz`. You can download it from any OpenBSD mirror.

Comment: J.F is right-on with the first comment - more important than update issues, is configuring sshd _correctly_ vs. work around hacks; doesn't matter if a rsa1 key exists, in the end it shouldn't be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

On `/etc/rc` search for : `ssh-keygen -A` then delete this line. You should not recreate **any** keys at startup. I did this and i got no error warning on boot, but if anyone knows a "cleaner" way to do this, please answer! Also this work for OpenBSD only(i think) but should only be a matter of finding the right init script to remove this line on other unix variants.

Edit : If you want to preserve your init script if you ever need it to update your system do `cd /etc` then `cp rc rc.backup` . If you ever need your original script just remove `rc` and rename `rc.backup` to `rc`